# How to change default list of compilers in GVIM on Windows?

Tags: vim

I found that the default list of compilers (under menu item 'Tools/SeT Compiler') almost totally useless to me. There are some languages listed that I never heard of, but there are absent much wider popular languages like HTML, CSS, JavaScript(!), Visual Basic.
Is it possible to change the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compilers that are listed there are the ones that are distributed with vim and are nothing else then little plugins that certain options to parse the output for a particular compiler. (Mostly they only set the ['errorformat' option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'errorformat')

If you need other compilers, you can probably find them as plugins (available at the vim.org script section or at github) and install them as regular plugins with your vim. Vim then should be able to display them in the toolbar, once they are installed and available for your vim.

Please also read the help at [:help :compiler](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#:compiler)